# Create a colourgradient in ggplot using "fill"

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am facing the following problem:
I am trying to create a heatmap for my data using ggplot2 and everything worked fine and looks good, except the fact, that in my legend, my colour is divisioned into separate stages corresponding to the column "syn_count". Now I was wondering if there is any way that in the legend, the different stages can be represented as a gradient.

Here is my code:

```
all <- ggplot(Neu, aes(type, tag, fill = syn_count))+
  geom_tile()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=8),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 1, hjust = 1))+
  coord_fixed()+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGn")+
  labs(title="Inputs of All MeMe-Neurons", x="MeMe-Neuron", y="Inputneuron")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Number of Synapses"))
all
```

and corresponding my plot:
[My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ohD8.png)

I browsed through here and saw solutions with the library scales and scale_fill_gradient2. But since I faced some problem loading the library I was wondering if there is any way using the ggplot2 package without adding any other.

I hope someone here can help my and thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is an example dataframe:

```
Tag/syn_count/type
A   24         1
E   500        1
F   310        2
F   67         2
G   266        3
T   80         3
H   270        4
```

tag(chr)
type(chr)
syn_count(num)

Comment: `scale_fill_gradient2` is a function in package `ggplot2`, there's no need to load any other package.

Comment: You are right, it is my fault for not saying this, but on the other post the solution posted was: + scale_fill_gradient2(position="bottom" , low = "blue", mid = muted("blue"), high = "red", midpoint = median(df22$val)) 
with the function "muted" being in the library scales

Comment: If you replace `mid = muted("blue")` with `mid = "#3A3A98"` then that should work, as that's the direct output of how the `scales::muted` function changes the colour Blue. You can also use any other colour (e.g. "lightblue", "green", "#9900cc") that you want.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! But now I still have the same problem. The function only changed my colors used and not the way they are portrayed (discrete/continuous).

Comment: That might depend on how your data looks - is `syn_count` stored as numeric or factor/character? If you're able to give a sample of your data we can try and replicate your problem (`scale_fill_gradient2` works fine for me)

Comment: Sure thing! Sorry my bad, I was just so into the topic that I forgot to provide an example dataframe. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on `guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Number of Synapses"))`, you should insert in `lab()` the fill's title.

Here is an example:

```r
df = tibble(tag = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")[runif(100, 1, 10) %>% round()],
            syn_count = runif(100, 1, 500) %>% round(),
            type = runif(100, 1, 10) %>% round())

ggplot(df, aes(type, tag, fill = syn_count))+
  geom_tile()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=8),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 1, hjust = 1))+
  coord_fixed()+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGn")+
  # add legend title 
  labs(title="Inputs of All MeMe-Neurons",
       x="MeMe-Neuron",
       y="Inputneuron",
       fill="Number of Synapses")   # HERE your legend's title
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any explanation as to why guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Number of Synapses")) is messing up with the plot? I would like to know just to avoid future mistakes.

Comment: The issue lies within the guide_legend() function because, even if you use scale_fill_distiller(palette = “YlGn", guide = guide_legend(title="Number of Synapses”)), the problem persists. It seems that parameters such as override.aes or available_aes might be influencing the scale transformation